# Unable to choose CakePHP in Laragon quick app

Tags: cakephp, laragon

I have installed PHP, but the turtorial I was following was able to choose Cakephp in quickapp after installing php. But I don't have the choice. Is there something I need to install? Won't Laragon be able to recognise Cakephp and install upon selection.

[image: Laragon]

Answer (score 0):

Quick app > Configuration

remove hashes at beginning of CakePHP create project code:

Old:
`### CakePHP=composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app %s`

New:
`CakePHP=composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app %s`

When you go back to Quick app you will see CakePHP above Symfony